# jQuery global variable undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read the enteredValue variable  outside the function but the value outside the function remains undefined:

```
var enteredValue;

$("input").on("keydown",function search(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert($(this).val());
        enteredValue = $(this).val().trim().toUpperCase()
        console.log("Code inside: " + enteredValue); //value is read
    }
});

console.log("Code outside : " + enteredValue); //value undefined
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add to code snippet..!

Comment: are you getting correct value in alert message?

Comment: nothing is wrong. `enteredValue` is undefined until you press a key in your input file

Comment: You are trying to read the value when it hasn't been initialized yet... code inside event handler is executed after the `console.log` written outside.

Comment: agreed with @gurvinder372  . Please check here:-https://jsfiddle.net/cpd4u5La/ (when page loaded check the console)

Comment: Can I somehow make the value available outside the function i.e. when I log the Code outside I see the same value inside the function?

Comment: Just initialise it as a `String` (or whatever datatype you need) in the beginning: `var enteredValue = "";`

Comment: @MasterYoda the value is still not the one I am declaring in the function